# How to add year and change date format in top GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome, customization, date, design

Currently the top panel has the time like this in this format:

[image: Date & Time in top GNOME panel]

But is there any way I can add the current year to that? And also a way of rearranging/changing the date format (though this is just something that I would preferably like in the answer but the main thing I want is the year)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.